# NoClassDefFoundError error message in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate

I am running a program on eclipse and I keep getting this error:

Unable to initialize main class com.logic.AddProduct
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session

Any explainations?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate JAR (hibernate-core i suppose) or onr of its dependencies is probably not in your runtime classpath.

Comment: can you clarify?

Comment: Your error means that one of the required class for or.hibernate.Session is not in your classpath when you run the application. More info [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)